# How do I detect if a cross-domain popup or iframe finish loading?

Tags: javascript, iframe, popup, cross-domain

I'm opening a new window of a different domain from the host.
I want to start pushing URL fragments when it's done.
I've tried this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function checkPage() {
if (windowReference.document.readyState == 'complete') {
alert('Done')
return;
}
setTimeout('checkPage()',100);
}

var windowReference = window.open('popup.htm','WindowName');

setTimeout('checkPage()',100);
//-->
</script>
```

Credit: http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-58396.html

But as the popup is cross-domain, the host cannot access `windowReference.document`.

Any other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, you do not have control over the dom (document), so it's not possible to listen to any events of the popup.

Answer (score 0):

What about attaching on resize event on the host window and change width or height + or - 1 by from pop to trigger resize? Will it work on fully maximized window?

Answer (score 0):

Just use PostMessage for cross-domain communication.